# Image Upload Work In Postman But not work In Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to upload the image to the server. The api is working fine with the postman, I am getting the success message, but when I tried in the app it is returning the error as mentioned below. I have implemented as follows:

```
  String base64Image;
  File _image;

  Future uploadImage(im) async {
    var user_id = 16;

    var url = 'http://ecommerce.yetfix.com/api/image-upload';
    var respons = await http.post(Uri.parse(url.toString()), body: {
      "user_id": user_id.toString(),
      "img_url": im
    });

    setState(() {
      if (respons.body.isNotEmpty) {
        var imgRe = json.decode(respons.body);
        print(imgRe);
      }
    });
  }


  final picker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    var pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery,
        imageQuality: 50,
        maxHeight: 500.0,
        maxWidth: 500.0);

    setState(() {
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        _image = File(pickedFile.path);
        base64Image = base64Encode(_image.readAsBytesSync());
      } else {
        print('No image selected.');
      }
    });
    uploadImage(_image);
  }
```

The error in the logcat from app

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type '_File' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
E/flutter ( 5521): #0      CastMap.forEach.<anonymous closure> (dart:_internal/cast.dart:288:25)
E/flutter ( 5521): #1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
E/flutter ( 5521): #2      CastMap.forEach (dart:_internal/cast.dart:287:13)
E/flutter ( 5521): #3      mapToQuery (package:http/src/utils.dart:17:7)
E/flutter ( 5521): #4      Request.bodyFields= (package:http/src/request.dart:137:12)
E/flutter ( 5521): #5      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:87:17)
E/flutter ( 5521): #6      BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter ( 5521): #7      post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
E/flutter ( 5521): #8      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
E/flutter ( 5521): #9      post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
E/flutter ( 5521): #10     _ImageUploadState.uploadImage (package:flutter_app_push/main.dart:32:25)
E/flutter ( 5521): #11     _ImageUploadState.getImage (package:flutter_app_push/main.dart:62:5)
E/flutter ( 5521): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are sending the file but it needs this String.
Instead of

```
 uploadImage(_image);
```

Do this

```
 uploadImage(base64Image );
```

Comment: When i send uploadImage(base64Image ) error return [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
E/flutter (13450): <!DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (13450): ^
E/flutter (13450): 
E/flutter (13450): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)

Comment: try commenting this line  var imgRe = json.decode(respons.body); just check this first  print(response.body); it is success or not

Comment: what did you get at response?

Comment: I think response.body return !DOCTYPE html>
E/flutter (18037): ^
E/flutter (18037): 
E/flutter (18037): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1404:5)
E/flutter (18037): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.parseNumber (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1271:9)
E/flutter (18037): #2      _ChunkedJsonParser.parse (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:936:22)
E/flutter (18037): #3      _parseJson (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:40:10)

Comment: think? have not you checked the response ?

Comment: I check the response and response is the same